# Loadrunner 12.55 (community edition) parallel Controller for testing 2 different URL's at same time

Tags: loadrunner

I'm new to LoadRunner. I'm using LoadRunner 12.55 (community edition). My current scenario is, I have two URL's one with new code and one with old code. I need to find the mean value and throughput for the two URL's separately to find if the new code's performance is increased. But the condition is I need to test both the URL's at the same time. And I need the reports separately for both the URL's. Is it possible? Pls help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply produce two test scripts and run them together.   Or, you may run two independent tests and then use the cross scenario analysis to join the two test sets in the analysis to observe differences.

I would recommend that you name your timers (transactions) uniquely in each test script to ease the identification of response from build A vs build A+1

As you are new to LoadRunner, at a minimum your management owes you some time to go through the self paced tutorial before engaging in actual work.  Ideally, you should be paired with a mentor for a period of time as well.  If your management is unwilling to engage in either then you would do well to question whether they are interested more in the quality of the output or the ability to bill for the effort.